# SQL performance of a large number of sum()s

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

Within my J2EE web application, I need to generate a bar chart representing the percentage of `users` in the system with specific `alerts`. (EDIT - I forgot to mention, the graph only deals with alerts associated with the first `situation`of each user, thus the `min(date)` ).

A simplified (but structurally similar) version of my database schema is as follows :

```
users { id, name }
situations { id, user_id, date }
alerts { id, situation_id,  alertA, alertB }
```

where `users` to `situations` are 1-n, and `situations` to `alerts` are 1-1.

I've omitted datatypes but the alerts (alertA and B) are booleans. In my *actual* case, there are many such alerts (30-ish).

So far, this is what I have come up with :

```
select sum(alerts.alertA), sum(alerts.alertB)
form alerts, (
    select id, min(date)
    from situations
    group by user_id) as situations
where situations.id = alerts.situation_id;
```

and then divide these sums by

```
select count(users.id) from users;
```

This seems far from ideal.

Your recommendations/advice as to how to improve as query would be most appreciated (or maybe I need to re-think my database schema)...

Thanks,

Anthony

PS. I was also thinking of using a trigger to refresh a chart specific table whenever the alerts table is updated but I guess that's a subject for a different query (if it turns out to be problematic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, think about your schema again. You will have a lot of different alerts and you probably don't want to add a single column for every one of those.

Consider changing your `alerts` table to something like `{ id, situation_id, type, value }` where `type` would be `(A,B,C,....)` and `value` would be your boolean.

Your task to calculate the percentages would then split up into:

**(1) Count the total number of users:**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM users
```

**(2) Find the "first" situation for each user:**

```
SELECT situations.id, situations.user_id
-- selects the minimum date for every user_id
FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(date) AS min_date
      FROM situations
      GROUP BY user_id) AS first_situation
-- gets the situations.id for user with minimum date
JOIN situations ON
  first_situation.user_id = situations.user_id AND
  first_situation.min_date = situations.date
-- limits number of situations per user to 1 (possible min_date duplicates)
GROUP BY user_id
```

**(3) Count users for whom an alert is set in at least one of the situations in the subquery:**

```
SELECT
  alerts.type,
  COUNT(situations.user_id)
FROM ( ... situations.user_id, situations.id ... ) AS situations
JOIN alerts ON
  situations.id = alerts.situation_id
WHERE
  alerts.value = 1
GROUP BY
  alerts.type
```

Put those three steps together to get something like:

```
SELECT
  alerts.type,
  COUNT(situations.user_id)/users.total
FROM (SELECT situations.id, situations.user_id
      FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(date) AS min_date
            FROM situations
            GROUP BY user_id) AS first_situation
      JOIN situations ON
        first_situation.user_id = situations.user_id AND
        first_situation.min_date = situations.date
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) AS situations
JOIN alerts ON
  situations.id = alerts.situation_id
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM users) AS users
WHERE
  alerts.value = 1
GROUP BY
  alerts.type
```

*All queries written from my head without testing. Even if they don't work exactly like that, you should still get the idea!*

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention that I'm only interested in the `alerts`associated with the first `situation`- thus the `min(date)`. I have amended my original question accordingly.

Comment: I've actually already contemplated restructuring the alerts to a one alert per row model. On the web application side this would mean that my `Alerts`class would just contain a list of Alert items and I'd need to do a bit of rewiring. My isAlertA() methods would just return a contains() or something along those lines - not particularly problematic. In my real-world application, `Situations`also contains a number of calculated metrics. Do you think these would benefit from a similar treatment? Many Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer in regard to the 'first situation' issue. I hope that helps!

Comment: Regarding the calculated metrics for `situations`. It depends. If those were a limited number of different calculations I would put those as columns directly into `situations`.
If instead those metrics are all calculated the same way, but i.e. just for a different subset of data or the number of metrics will be bigger in the future (or is big already), then I would go with the extra table approach, just as with the alerts.

Comment: Nope, they all rely on different calculations and they aren't likely to change significantly in the short to mid term. I think I'll leave them in`situations`as suggested - if nothing else it'll safe me the refactoring! Many Thanks

Comment: Last question :) Would this be a good scenario for a database view (I've never really used them)?

Comment: Creating a stored procedure or a view would reduce complexity outside the database in your J2EE web application. You would only need to call that procedure or select from the view, which would be a one liner. You could also modify your query later on, without touching your J2EE soure code, because it is entirely stored on the mysql server.
Read more on when to use views:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483580/mysql-views-when-to-use-when-not-to
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/when-to-use-views-in-mysql